# Hot to paste a text copied from a file using cmd " Get-Content -Raw file_name | clip " to a new file in another directory

Tags: windows, powershell, echo, file-get-contents

I copy a text from .cpp file using the command-line using this command `Get-Content -Raw file_name | clip` in Windows 10
and I'm trying to paste that text into another file in another directory

I've tried using the `cat` command to redirect the output to a new file like 
 `cat -Raw file_name > path_to_new_file` 
 it works , but I want to paste the same text to more than one path

the point , is there any keyword or alias that store the text copied earlier , to paste it where I want
or is there any keyword or alias return the last copy in the clipboard

Can someone please help me with this issue? How can I paste the copied text to a file in another directory using the command prompt ?

I've tried using the `cat` command to redirect the output to a new file like 
 `cat -Raw file_name > path_to_new_file` 
 it works , but I want to paste the same text to more than one path

Comment: Why do you want to use the clipboard? Why not just write to the target files directly?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , yeah I've tried using the `cat` command to redirect the output to a new target like `cat -Raw file_name > path_to_new_file
`   then I want to paste the same text to another file

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks it work , I used your code `$row = Get-Clipboard` then i can paste the text anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recall the clipboard contents, use `Get-Clipboard`:

```
# put content in clipboard
Get-Content -Raw file_name |Set-Clipboard

# retrieve it as many times as you like
1..10 |ForEach-Object {
    Get-Clipboard
}
```

---

That being said, you don't need to use the clipboard - simply store the file contents in a variable and reference that:

```
# put content in variable
$rawContent = Get-Content -Raw file_name

Get-ChildItem .\path\to\target\files -Filter *.ext |ForEach-Object {
    # append to target file(s)
    $rawContent |Add-Content -LiteralPath $_.PSPath
}
```